# Uncaught Error: [vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm following [the official example](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/nested-routes.html) but I don't know why I get a blank page with this js error

> vue-router.esm.js?fe87:10 Uncaught Error: [vue-router] "path" is required in a route configuration.

Here is my two pages:

```
/:language/bar                     /:language/foo
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
| +---------+      |                  | +---------+     |
| | header  |      |                  | | header  |     |
| +---------+      |                  | +---------+     |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
| | bar          | |  +------------>  | | foo         | |
| |              | |                  | |             | |
| +--------------+ |                  | +-------------+ |
+------------------+                  +-----------------+
```

And this is how I'm trying to do it.

**My entrypoint js file:**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import router from './router';

// import some components

let vm = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router,
    components: {/*imported components*/},
});

vm.$language.current = vm.$route.params.language;
```

**My entrypoint html**

```
<body>
   <div id="app">
       <!-- this is the header, the common part -->
       <navbar fullname=''></navbar>

       <router-view></router-view>
   </div>
</body>
```

**My router**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Router from 'vue-router';

// import foo and bar components

Vue.use(Router);

let routes = [
    {
        path: '/:language',
        name: 'homepage',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'foo',
                component: Foo
            },
            {
                path: 'bar',
                component: Bar
            },
        ]
    }
];

export default new Router({routes,});
```

**My foo component**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>FOO</h1>
    </div>
</template>

<script>export default {};</script>
```

How do I fix this error?

Comment: You should add a component also for the parent.

Comment: @Nora you're right you're right you're right!! thx! you can add an answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should add a component also for the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Faced same issue but in my case:

*router/index.js*

```
import config from '@common/src/config'
...
...

{
  path: config.mobile_search,
  name: 'search',
  component: MobileSearch
}
```

*mobile_search* path was missed in config file.

So ensure you've added the proper path.

Answer (score -1):

Note: 
 1. try to use local registration for component
 2. For Nested Router :

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    { path: '/language/:id',
      component: language,
      children: [
        {
          // Bar will be rendered inside language's <router-view>
          // when /language/:id/bar is matched
          path: 'bar',
          component: Bar
        },
        {
          // Foo will be rendered inside language's <router-view>
          // when /language/:id/foo is matched
          path: 'foo',
          component: Foo
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
})
```

3. To export component:

```
    export default {
      name: "Foo"
    };
```